# Matching a hash from one file to another file hash and outputting both to a third file to match them

Tags: python, hash, grep, match

I am trying to just speed up a really slow manual process and would love some help as im not to great at programming. I have a hash file1 which contains username and hash, and a file2 which contains the cracked hash and cleartext password. Right now I have to manually match the hash from file 2 to file 1 so i can see which user it was for.

```
File1 
Administrator:asdsadasgkgdsuagduksa:hashishere:::

File 2
hashishere:Password123
```

I would like the third file output to look something like this

```
File 3
Administrator:Password123
or anything like this that includes both the user and password on the same line
```

Is this possible? Really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Read the files in, use two dictionaries to log the data, use the Username dictionary to get the corresponding hash then use that hash on the password dict to get the password. Concatenate the result in whatever string format you like

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).